# How to make input statements optional?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was having a small issue while I was trying to write a program to calculate simple interest in Python.

```py
def si(p,r=100,t=2):
    return (p*r*t)/100
x=float(input("Enter principal amount"))
y=float(input("Enter rate"))
z=float(input("Enter time"))
print (si(x,y,z))
```

I want to make y and z optional. Any idea how can I do? If I leave it blank and press enter it shows error.

Comment: It shows an error because you're immediately trying to convert it to a float, which fails for the empty string. You will instead want to do something along the lines of 1) retrieve input 2) test validity 3a) if valid, convert to float 3b) otherwise, use default value or raise error

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is using `or`
    def si(p,r,t):
        return (p*r*t)/100

```
x = float(input("Enter principal amount: "))
y = float(input("Enter rate: ") or 100)
z = float(input("Enter time: ") or 2)

print (si(x,y,z))

Enter principal amount: 1
Enter rate: 
Enter time: 
2.0
```

But correct way is validating input before converting it to float

```
def si(p,r=100,t=2): 
    return (p*r*t)/100 

x = input("Enter principal amount: ") 
y = input("Enter rate: ") 
z = input("Enter time: ") 

def validate(param): 
    return float(param) if param else 1

print (si(validate(x), validate(y), validate(z)))
```

Output:

```
Enter principal amount: 1
Enter rate: 
Enter time: 
0.01
```

Comment: With the 2nd, you could `else None` and add checking for None in `si` function, and then assigning default (just like avoiding mutable default arguments does). :)

Comment: @h4z3 Nope :) Try it) `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'float' and 'NoneType'`

Comment: Yup. ;P `return float(param) if param else None` works - inline if/else substitutes the whole value. It would a type error if it was `return float(param if param else None)` but it isn't ;)

Comment: @h4z3 `float(None)` ? really? :)

Comment: I never said `float(None)`. I said to put `else None` instead of `else 1`, making it `return float(param) if param else None`. Which evaluates to either `float(param)` or `None` (NOT `float(None)`)

Comment: @h4z3 ok, sorry, I missunderstood you